# Combining grouped pairs into a single group in R

Tags: r, fuzzy-comparison

I'm doing a large fuzzy matching task in R, matching similar store names to each other. In some cases, there are multiple records linked to a single store, and this has resulted in pairs where A = B, B = C, and A = C. I'd like to combine these to a single group id code so that they can all be combined together. See this table below:

```
PairID   Store name
1        Quick Stop
2        TD's Food Shop
2        TD's Food Shops
3        TD's Food Shops
3        TD's Food Shop 1
4        TD's Food Shop
4        TD's Food Shop 1
```

Using R/tidyverse I can't figure out a way to combine the PairID's for 2, 3, and 4 in this example into a single group. Have others found a way to do this?

###EDIT

It looks like the refinr package in R does this pretty easily (https://github.com/ChrisMuir/refinr). It's an automated implementation of OpenRefine, which for > 100,000 records is what I need--don't have the ability to match manually. The code would look something like this:

```
df<-as_tibble(c("QuikStop","TJ's Foods","TJs Foods","TJ's Food"))
df$match<-n_gram_merge(df$value)
```

The result looks like this

```
value           match
QuikStop        QuikStop
TJ's Foods      TJ's Food
TJs Foods       TJ's Food
TJ's Food       TJ's Food
```

The weights for the match can be tweaked using parameters from stringdist. Thanks for the advice from commenters!

Comment: In this case do you already know you want 2, 3, and 4 combined, and just need to do it? Or do you also need code to figure out that 2, 3, and 4 should be combined?

Comment: Basically the first--I just need to know how to do it. These are all stores that have the same street address, so I'm fine assuming that they're the same store with slightly different names. Because I'm being conservative in setting up pairs, I'm fine grouping all stores that are somehow connected, even if they aren't directly paired.

Answer (score 0):

This can actually become an extremely difficult problem if you want or need to group the rows together by similar store names without exogenously specifying how many real stores there are or what their official names are. This is because you will inevitably end up with fuzzily overlapping clusters, and violations of transitivity at any given string-distance thresholding or minimization. A will be closest to B, B will be closest to C, and C will *not* be closest to A, and then what? A and B can't be the same store while C is the same store as B but not A!

Assuming you are comfortable with specifying a vector of canonical store names, then I recommend the following, which just finds the canonical store name that's closest to the name in each row, and makes a new column of those closest canonical names. Then you can group by that new column's values, and collapse the store IDs into comma-delimited vectors, or whatever.

```r
library(future)
library(stringdist)
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'magrittr'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:purrr':
#> 
#>     set_names
#> The following object is masked from 'package:tidyr':
#> 
#>     extract

data <- tribble(
  ~PairID, ~`Store name`,
  1,       "Quick Stop",
  2,       "TD's Food Shop",
  2,       "TD's Food Shops",
  3,       "TD's Food Shops",
  3,       "TD's Food Shop 1",
  4,       "TD's Food Shop",
  4,       "TD's Food Shop 1"
)

standard_names <- c("Quick Stop", "TD's Food Shop")

plan(multiprocess)

data %<>% mutate(
  closest_name = 
    stringdistmatrix(`Store name`, standard_names, method = "jw") %>% 
    apply(1, function(x) which(x == min(x))) %>% 
    extract(standard_names, .)
)

data
#> # A tibble: 7 x 3
#>   PairID `Store name`     closest_name  
#>    <dbl> <chr>            <chr>         
#> 1      1 Quick Stop       Quick Stop    
#> 2      2 TD's Food Shop   TD's Food Shop
#> 3      2 TD's Food Shops  TD's Food Shop
#> 4      3 TD's Food Shops  TD's Food Shop
#> 5      3 TD's Food Shop 1 TD's Food Shop
#> 6      4 TD's Food Shop   TD's Food Shop
#> 7      4 TD's Food Shop 1 TD's Food Shop

combined_pairIDs <- 
  data %>% 
  group_by(closest_name) %>% 
  summarize_at("PairID", ~ toString(order(unique(.x)))) %>% 
  ungroup()

combined_pairIDs
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   closest_name   PairID 
#>   <chr>          <chr>  
#> 1 Quick Stop     1      
#> 2 TD's Food Shop 1, 2, 3
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Note that there's a possibility for an error here, which I'm deliberately leaving in. What if one of the rows has a name that's equally close to two or more canonical names? It will try and extract more than one value from `standard_names`, which isn't allowed. If such ties do happen, then you have to decide how you want to break them, and what they might be indicating about the nature of the data.

Comment: Thanks! I've thought about the transitivity issue. This is a listing of stores from government records across years, and I've grouped before stringdist based on street address. The records change across years in ways similar to the sample data I posted. I'm using a conservative cutoff when creating the pairs to try to prevent false matches. Basically, I'm fine with A, B, and C being grouped together even if A and C weren't paired, though I will do a quality check after the fact. I also don't have a canonical list--the only way I could imagine that would be something like OpenRefine.

Comment: I was actually going to suggest using OpenRefine for this. Great tool.

Comment: There's definitely network analysis algorithms out there that do proper cluster analysis, but I don't really know them. (Never even heard of OpenRefine.) I'm almost positive, though, that you can use those clustering algorithms to rank all the observed store names by their average string distance to all the other observed names (average edge weight?). Take the top n of those, and you have your n canonical store names, to plug into my code. Best way I can think to do it.

Comment: There's an R implementation of OpenRefine (refinr) that did it--see the solution above. Thanks for the input--it was helpful.